# django inspectdb not getting all my tables

Tags: python, django, legacy, inspectdb

Running the "inspectdb" with django and it returns a model file but the model file is missing some of the tables in my db. It actually has a table that was put in awhile ago but later deleted or replaced. Do I need to update my DB or something, it seems like django is looking at an older "version" of the db.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, my 'Name' in my settings.py was incorrect so it was looking at the wrong database